# Video Interview During Work hours

Tags: new-job

I work in the hospitality industry and I am looking for a new challenge, I have successfully applied to a wonderful property and managed to have the first set of interviews. I just got a mail yesterday that I have an interview set at this time on Tuesday with the general
Manager. The mail differed for the first round of interviews as they proposed me different times since they knew i was working. This time I believe since it’s the GM I don’t have an opportunity to change the time let’s say. I am quit annoyed as I am
Free all day monday, but I don’t believe it would be right to ask to change the date

I believe the interview won’t take too long however where would I be able to do it at work. I am so worried and bothered, lockers, go out, bathroom even? Anyone else can suggest something? Any previous  experience?

Thank you

Comment: Related: [Rescheduling a Coveted Interview.](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/35878) [Where to take phone interview while at work.](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/79451) [How should I schedule phone interviews while employed?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/3368) [How to interview for a new job when working full time?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/18626)

Comment: Also: [What are your thoughts on doing a video/Skype interview in the car?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/55051) [What's the proper/professional way to interview for a new job while currently employed?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/21296) [How should I ask for time off to attend an interview?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/5963)

Comment: I usually worked around it either taking the rest of the day off, or using lunch hours.

Answer (score 1):

I would not advise doing it in the premises, you wont be as natural and you will be nervous.

I usually worked around the availability problem for interviews during the day either taking the rest of the day off, or using lunch hours.

If the GM wont want to change the time of the interview knowing you have a full-time job, it would not be probably a place were you would want to work.